# Let $p,q$ be irrational numbers, such that, $p^2$ and $q^2$ are relatively prime. Show that $\sqrt{pq}$ is also irrational.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers

**Progress:**

> Since, $p,q$ are irrationals and $p^2$ and $q^2$ are relatively prime, thus, $p^2\cdot{q^2}$ cannot be a proper square, so, $pq$ is also irrational. Suppose, $pq=k$, then: $$\sqrt{k}\cdot\sqrt{k}=\sqrt{pq}\cdot\sqrt{pq}=k$$
>   Which implies that $\sqrt{pq}$ is irrational, since, $k$ is irrational and that $p^2\cdot{q^2}$ cannot be a proper square being $p^2$ and $q^2$ relatively prime and that concludes the proof.

The above lines are my attempt to prove the assertion. Is the proof correct? If not then how can I improve or disprove it.

Regrads

Comment: Are $p^2$ and $q^2$ integers? If so, you seemed to have used the facts that (a) the square root of an integer is either an integer or irrational, and (b) the square root of an irrational number is irrational, without explicitly stating them or justifying them

Comment: Yes, $p^2$ and $q^2$ are integers, since I stated they are relatively prime. I also used those two facts you mentioned. @Henry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part is correct, but you could clarify it a little bit:

> Since $p$ and $q$ are irrational, they are not integers
>
> Since $p$ and $q$ are not integers, $p^2$ and $q^2$ are not perfect squares
>
> Since in addition to that $p^2$ and $q^2$ are relatively prime, $p^2q^2$ is not a perfect square
>
> Since $p^2q^2$ is not a perfect square, $\sqrt{p^2q^2}=pq$ is irrational

---

The second part is somewhat obscure, but you could simply use the following argument instead:

> Since $pq$ is irrational, it is not a multiple of two integers
>
> Since $pq$ is not a multiple of two integers, it is not a perfect square
>
> Since $pq$ is not a perfect square, $\sqrt{pq}$ is irrational

Comment: @user18724: Thank you :)

Comment: By the way, what I just noticed is that the second argument from the first part is not necessarily true. 

"Since $p$ and $q$ are not integers, $p^2$ and $q^2$ are not perfect squares", here is one example: $p=\sqrt{8}$ and $q=\sqrt{2}$ where both are not integers, but raising their power to $2$ yields $16=\sqrt{8^2}\cdot{\sqrt{2^2}}=8\cdot{2}$, which is a perfect square, since $4^2=16$ @barak manos

Comment: @user18724: You're wrong. The perfect square that you are talking about is $p^2q^2$, I was referring to $p^2$ AND $q^2$ (separated).

Comment: Ok, got it. @barak manos

Answer (score 1):

Except that you haven't proved $p^2 * q^2 $ cannot be perfect square, rest of the proof is correct.

Since $p^2 $ and $q^2$ are relatively prime, they do not have common prime factors. And they are not perfect squares. Else p,q would be rational numbers. This is necessary since 25, 4 are relatively prime but their product is perfect square.

Hence atleast one of the prime factors of p^2 and q^2 will be raised to an odd power in prime factorisation and those primes will be distinct. So   $p^2 * q^2 $ cannot be perfect square

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\sqrt{pq}$ is rational, say $\sqrt{pq} = \dfrac mn$ where $m$ and $m$ are positive, relatively prime integers. Then $p^2 q^2 = \dfrac{m^4}{n^4}$ where $p^2q^2$ is an integer. Since $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime integers, then $m^4$ and $n^4$ are also relatively prime integers. It follows that $n^4=1$ and hence $n=1$. So we find that $p^2q^2 = m^4$ for some positive integer $m$.

Since $p^2$ and $q^2$ are relatively prime integers,then any prime divisor of $m$ cannot be a common divisor of both $p^2$ and $q^2$. It follow that there must be relatively prime positive integers $a$ and $b$ such that $m = ab$, $\;p^2 = a^4$, and $q^2 = b^4$. Hence $p=a^2$ and $q=b^2$, which implies that $p$ and $q$ are rational (integers). By contradiction, $\sqrt{pq}$ must be irrational.